# Azure SQL Data Warehouse - how to drop a database?

Tags: azure-synapse

How to drop an Azure SQL Data Warehouse database? drop database T-SQL command does not apply to ASDW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support `DROP DATABASE` as per the current documentation:

[image: DROP DATABASE documentation]

Delete your database via the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a doc bug. You can connect to the **master** database and run:

```
DROP DATABASE <database name>
```

I've already updated the docs to reflect this.